# I wrote a python script to perform google search for multiple keywords at once but it's throwing an error

Tags: python, search, automation, google-api, google-search

```
import csv
import time
from googlesearch import search

def fetch_search_results(keywords):
    search_results = []

    for keyword in keywords:
        results = []
        for url in search(keyword, num_results=3):
            if 'burj' in url:
            results.append(url)
        search_results.append(','.join(results))
        delay()  # Add a delay between requests

    return search_results

# Function to introduce a delay between requests
def delay():
    time.sleep(2)  # Adjust the delay duration as needed

# Read keywords from a CSV file
def read_keywords_from_csv(file_path):
    keywords = []

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            keyword = row[0]  # Assuming the keyword is in the first column
            keywords.append(keyword)

    return keywords

# Write search results to a CSV file
def write_results_to_csv(results, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Keyword', 'Search Results'])
        for keyword, result in zip(keywords, results):
            writer.writerow([keyword, result])

# Example usage
csv_file_path = "Surat_unmatched.csv"  # Update with your CSV file path
keywords = read_keywords_from_csv(csv_file_path)
results = fetch_search_results(keywords)

output_csv_file_path = "search_results.csv"  # Update with desired output file path
write_results_to_csv(results, output_csv_file_path)`
```

this script is throwing an error:

```
429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3DAvadh%252BUtopia%252BSurat%26num%3D3%26hl%3Den%26start%3D0&hl=en
```

this is the script and google thinks that this is suspicious — can this be solved if I used google's API?

I was expecting an output in a csv with potential links of the webpages that has a mention of Burj

Comment: The Google search API (Custom Search JSON API) will allow 100 queries per day at no cost. If you need more than that then you'll need to pay

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you were banned by google because you had sent too many requests in a given amount of time(rate limiting).
As far as I know, using google api instead of scraping might be a better way. However, you can rotate your ip address to distribute your requests, and this could help to avoid rate limits.